# ASP.NET MVC: Display a link to another action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a bill", "Create", new { controller = "Bill"});
```

This is the code I used to add an link to Create method in Bill controller.

But in the view I saw

```
Add a bill (/Bill/Create):
```

So, how can I remove the brackets? (/Bill/Create).

And, I also want this link to act as a button instead of a , how can I do that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is strange what brackets you are talking about. Assuming the default routes both:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a bill", "Create", new { controller = "Bill" })
```

and:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a bill", "Create", "Bill")
```

are equivalent and should generate the following markup:

```
<a href="/Bill/Create">Add a bill</a>
```

As far as your question about the button is concerned you could use a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Bill"))
{
   <input type="submit" value="Add a bill" />
}
```

Comment: Yeah, In html source, I see "<a href="/Bill/Create">Add a bill</a>
" But browser rendered as that what I said.

Comment: @user469652, yes it is possible that it is a CSS issue. Try disabling all style sheets temporary to see if this makes any difference.