# Unable to use Hyperlink on my web app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, hyperlink

I want to insert a hyperlink which will take users to a 'forgot password' page. I have created a hyperlink on my login page, however once clicked on it takes users to the next page which is not what I want, can anyone help and see where I have gone wrong.

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
        SB.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"loginActionURL\" value=\"");
        SB.Append(ApplicationUtility.FormatURL("/Stock/Login"));
        SB.Append("\" />");
        litLoginActionHidden.Text = SB.ToString();

        if (ViewData["ERROR"] != null)
        {
            StringBuilder ES = new StringBuilder();
            ES.Append("<table border=1><tr><td  class=\"ErrorText\">");
            ES.Append(ViewData["ERROR"].ToString());
            ES.Append("</td></tr></table>");
            errormsg.Text = ES.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            errormsg.Text = " ";
        }


        litApplicationName.Text = "Stock Calibration";
    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ApplicationUtility.FormatURL("/Stock/ForgotPassword"));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If this is asp.net mvc why not just call the login page method to return it's view?

Comment: it is a asp.net mvc. How would I call the login page method to return the view?

Comment: Should should be able to do it through an action link `@Html.ActionLink("Link Header", "Action", "Controler")`. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770826/asp-net-mvc-display-a-link-to-another-action) is another similar question that explains it a little more fully. (See the answer from Darin Dimitrov)